# Using synonym in Oracle DB in SYS schema

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

There is V_$SQL view in **SYS** schema. In *public* schema I have synonym v$sql for it. If I connect to DB with my user **dbuser** and I try to get something from v$sql it works. Problem is that when I change schema to **SYS** (but still I am dbuser) and try to use v$sql again my synonym doesn't work. I get error

```
[42000][942] ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

If I use V_$SQL instead of v$sql it works. Why after schema change my synonym doesn't work?

Comment: how do you change current schema? and precisely why do you change current schema?

Comment: I change schema by ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = SYS. I'm just learning Oracle DB and I observed that this doesn't work

Comment: I believe that you messed something. It needs to work. Btw, normally we do not need to change current schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have your current schema set to 'SYS', then `V$SQL` resolves to `SYS.V$SQL`, which you do not have access to.

**"But, I checked DBA_OBJECTS and there *is* no SYS.V$SQL!!!"**

`SYS.V$SQL` is a fixed table.  It does not show up in DBA_OBJECTS.  You can see it in V$FIXED_TABLE.

```
select * from v$fixed_table
where name like 'V$SQL';
```

> ```
> +-------+------------+------+-----------+--------+
> | NAME  | OBJECT_ID  | TYPE | TABLE_NUM | CON_ID |
> +-------+------------+------+-----------+--------+
> | V$SQL | 4294951148 | VIEW |     65537 |      0 |
> +-------+------------+------+-----------+--------+
> ```

The `SYS` schema is special and weird and for Oracle's use only.  It's best not to mess around with it.

Comment: But I can query `V$SQL` (also with schema prefix - `SYS.V$SQL` it works too) if I am in  "SYS" schema as user `dbuser`. The problem is only with usage of v$sql synonym in "SYS" schema. v$sql synonym is created in PUBLIC schema.

Comment: Your comment contradicts your post.  In your post you say you cannot select from `V$SQL` when your current schema is SYS.  In your comment you say you can.  Perhaps update your question with a list of SELECT statements that work for you and a list that does not.  Also, is this a custom synonym?  What is its name?

Comment: No. I wrote that _If I use V_$SQL instead of v$sql it works._ Only synonym doesn't work in SYS schema. No it's not custom synonym it is auto generated synonym v$sql

Comment: Right.  My answer explains why trying to use V$SQL does not work when your schema is SYS.  Again, the reason is that there is a fixed table named SYS.V$SQL, so your query attempt resolves to that object and not the public synonym.

Comment: Okay. Last thing I don't understand. Why I don't have access to public synonym v$sql when I am in SYS schema but I have access when I am in my user schema? I thought that synonyms from PUBLIC schema are accessible from anywhere..

Comment: Oracle only uses public synonyms when you don't have an object with that name in your schema.  E.g., If my schema is `user1` and I `SELECT * FROM tab1`, it will use `user1.tab1` before going to `PUBLIC.tab1`.  It's not that `SYS` "doesn't have access to" the public synonym -- it's that is not even looking for `PUBLIC.V$SQL` because it finds `SYS.V$SQL` first.